# Solving the system of equations $\begin{cases}\frac{V_1}{sL}+\frac{V_1-V_2}{R}=I_s \\ \frac{V_2-V_1}{R}+\frac{V_2}{1/sC} = 0\end{cases}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, systems-of-equations

I have two equations and I'm trying to solve for $V_2$. The equations are:$$\begin{cases}\frac{V_1}{sL}+\frac{V_1-V_2}{R}=I_s\\ \frac{V_2-V_1}{R}+\frac{V_2}{1/sC} = 0\end{cases}$$

If I solve the second equation for $V_1$, I get$$V_1=V_2 (sRC+1) .$$

It all goes down hill when I substitute $V_1$ into first equation. I end up getting $$\frac{I_s}{\frac{1}{sL}+\frac{sC}{R}} .$$

However the correct answer is
$$\frac{s I_s}{C[s^2+\frac{R}{L}s +\frac{1}{LC}]} .$$

Can someone help me walk through this step by step to figure out why I am getting the wrong answer.

Comment: Where does $V_b$ appear in any of the above? What are you trying to solve for?

Comment: Sorry it was $V_2$

Comment: I find maxima (wxmaxima) useful for symbolic calculations. A bit cumbersome, but free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I plug $V_1=V_2(sRC+1)$ and $V_1-V_2=V_2sRC$ into
$$\frac{V_1}{sL}+\frac{V_1-V_2}{R}=I_s$$ 
I get
$$
\begin{align}
V_2 \left(\frac{sRC+1}{sL}+sC\right)&=I_s\\
V_2 \frac{sRC+1+s^2LC}{sL} &= I_s
\end{align}
$$
which means
$$V_2= \frac{I_ssL}{sRC+1+s^2LC}.$$
For some reason, in the answer from your book they continued to get
$$V_2= \frac{I_ssL}{sRC+1+s^2LC} = \frac{I_ssL}{LC \left(\frac{sR}L + \frac1{LC} + s^2\right)} = \frac{I_ss}{C \left(\frac{sR}L + \frac1{LC} + s^2\right)}.$$

Comment: The terms $\frac{R}{L}$ (frequency of sorts) and $\frac{1}{LC}$ (square of resonant frequency) have physical interpretations for electrical engineers...

Comment: I see. So that's probably the reason why they did not leave that it that form but continued until they had there those expressions.

Comment: Yes this is algebra for an output voltage using the laplace transform.